# Retaining Activity state

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton

In my application it contains some secure information so I implemented passlock. It is opening the passlock screen and when entered credentials application starts from first activity but what I need is, from which activity I have paused I should get that activity and navigation from there. How can I do this? I tried with `android:label="@string/app_name"` and `android:launchMode="singleTask"`but its not working as desired. Please help me.

I referred with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249651/know-when-to-show-a-passcode-lock)

Thank you in advance

Comment: handle configuration changes.

Comment: I tried that what i need is i have 3 activities i have navigated from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. now at i am at third screen and now if i press home button all the activities will be paused and application goes into background. and when i open the app by long press on home buttton passcode screen will appear and when entered pas code now i need to get 3rd activity screen from where i pressed home button. How can i do this